# How to use an external object in a struct callback such as when appending data to a CSV?

Tags: csv, struct, callback, rust

My understanding was that objects created outside of the scope are available inside the scope (hence things such as shadowing allowed), but it does not seem to work in this scenario:

```
extern crate csv;
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;
use std::path::Path;
use std::time::SystemTime;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Event {
    time: SystemTime,
    value: u32,
}

impl Event {
    fn new(t: SystemTime, n: u32) -> Event {
        Event {
            time: SystemTime,
            value: n,
        }
    }
}

struct Process;

impl Process {
    fn new() -> Process {
        Process {}
    }

    fn start(&self) {
        loop {
            let now = SystemTime::now();
            let random_number: u32 = rand::thread_rng().gen();
            let event = Event::new(now, random_number);
            self.callback(event);
        }
    }

    fn callback(&self, event: Event) {
        println!("{:?}", event);
        wtr.write_record(&event).unwrap();
        wtr.flush().unwrap();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let file_path = Path::new("test.csv");
    let mut wtr = csv::Writer::from_path(file_path).unwrap();

    let process: Process = Process::new();
    process.start();
}
```

The errors are:

```
error[E0423]: expected value, found struct `SystemTime`
  --> src/main.rs:17:19
   |
17 |             time: SystemTime,
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^ constructor is not visible here due to private fields

error[E0425]: cannot find value `wtr` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:41:9
   |
41 |         wtr.write_record(&event).unwrap();
   |         ^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `wtr` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:42:9
   |
42 |         wtr.flush().unwrap();
   |         ^^^ not found in this scope
```

How can I append data (`Event`) to a CSV file from inside the callback function for `Process`?

Comment: What does the first error you've pasted have to do with your question?

Comment: @Shepmaster It has nothing to do with my question. I included it in for completeness as I didn't know how to fix it... Thank you for answering the question, solution 2 is appropriate as the callback function is implemented by a third party library and I do not control what it passes as arguments. I have to read up on lifetimes again and the where clause. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **strongly** encourage you to go back and re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/), specifically the chapter about [functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch03-03-how-functions-work.html). This code appears to show fundamental issues around the entire model of how functions work.

For example, the code attempts to make use of the variable `wtr` in the function `callback` without it being passed in either directly or indirectly.

If such code worked<sup>1</sup>, programmers would likely hate dealing with this language because it would be almost impossible to tell *what* and *where* the value `wtr` even came from.

The solution is straightforward: pass any value that a piece of code needs to that code. Then it's easy (or easier) to tell where the value came from. There are multiple avenues that can work.

1. Pass an argument to the `callback` method:

   ```
   use std::io::Write;

   impl Process {
       fn start<R>(&self, wtr: &mut csv::Writer<R>)
       where
           R: Write,
       {
           loop {
               // ...
               self.callback(wtr, event);
           }
       }

       fn callback<R>(&self, wtr: &mut csv::Writer<R>, event: Event)
       where
           R: Write,
       {
           // ...
       }
   }

   fn main() {
       // ...
       process.start(&mut wtr);
   }
   ```
2. Pass an argument to the constructor and save it inside the struct:

   ```
   use std::io::Write;

   struct Process<'a, R>
   where
       R: Write + 'a,
   {
       wtr: &'a mut csv::Writer<R>,
   }

   impl<'a, R> Process<'a, R>
   where
       R: Write,
   {
       fn new(wtr: &'a mut csv::Writer<R>) -> Self {
           Process { wtr }
       }

       // ...

       fn callback(&self, event: Event) {
           // ...
           self.wtr.write_record(event).unwrap();
           self.wtr.flush().unwrap();
       }
   }

   fn main() {
       // ...
       let process = Process::new(&mut wtr);
   }
   ```

The code has other issues in how it uses the CSV library that I'm ignoring because they are unrelated to your question. I encourage you to start with a simpler piece of code, get it working, then make it more complex. That way you are only dealing with simpler errors at first.

Once you understand this basic usage of functions, you may wish to learn about [*closures*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch13-01-closures.html). These allow you to "capture" variables from an outer scope and pass them in (in the same two methods as above) without having to deal with the specific count or type of variables.

> objects created outside of the scope are available inside the scope

This is true for a single function. It does not apply across functions.

> hence things such as shadowing allowed

Shadowing has nothing to to with scopes. You are allowed to shadow inside the same scope:

```
let a = Some(32);
let a = a.unwrap();
```

---

**1**.  Such languages exist; they are languages with [dynamic scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping) and some people prefer them. They are in the minority, programs written in these languages are hard to reason about!